# Using asdfree lodown to download all implicates of Survey of Consumer finance

Tags: r, survey

I am trying to download the complete Survey of Consumer Finance data files following the example in asdfree using lodown. The code works seamlessly and I am able to use it to download a single implicate for each year. I did not see in the catalog or example how to download all 5 implicates of the SCF.

I followed the code from asdfree for download the entire SCF. This results in one implicate of each year and replicate weights.

```
library(lodown)
lodown( "scf" , output_dir = file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , "SCF" ) )
```

I was expecting this to result in every implicate every year. Is there an option for the lodown command to have all implicates downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code doesn't only download a single implicate.  after following the steps on page http://asdfree.com/survey-of-consumer-finances-scf.html to get to the `scf_imp` object, here's how to take a look at the first few records of the first and fifth implicate.  thanks

```
# this list contains five data.frame objects
length( scf_imp )
sapply( scf_imp , class )

# first few records of the 1st and 5th implicate of the data set
head( scf_imp[[1]] )
head( scf_imp[[5]] )
```